# R color2D.matplot: how to fit colour scale with colour breaks at specific values?

Tags: r, colors, plot, scale

Good afternoon,

I was previously using the code:

```
image.plot(q,col=c("white","palegoldenrod","yellow","gold","darkorange","red","darkred","darkorchid4")
,breaks=c(0,1,100,500,1000,2500,5000,7500,10000),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",add=TRUE)
```

but I had trouble with showing values corresponding to each cell of the `matrix`.

So I decided to switch to `color2D.matplot.`..which shows corresponding values but with which I'm having trouble in parameterising the colour scale. I would like to have the same colour scale as the one I used in `image.plot`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should mention that `color2D.matplot` is from the `plotrix` package so people can track it down.

Comment: It looks to me like you may find it easiest to calculate `log(q)` and then plot with `image.plot(log(q), etc)`  to get the breakpoints you want.   But first, can you explain what "I had trouble..." means?  Perhaps a simple fix to your original `image.plot` call will solve the problem.